# MongoDB get data from files from gridFS with aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to get the files from a gridFS mongo database with a aggregate query?

I have the following query:

```
$ops = array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
                            "_id" =>  array('$lt' => new MongoId($id)),
                            "data.VisionId" => (string)$visionId,
                            "data.GroepNummer" => (string)$groepnummer,
                            "data.TypeFile" => ucfirst($typefile),
                            'data.Datum' => array('$gt' => $new_date, '$lte' => $datum),
                         )
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array(
            "uploadDate" => -1,
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$limit' => 1000
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            "_id" => array("Datum" => '$data.Datum',),
             "FirstId" => array('$first' => '$_id'),
        ),
    ),
);

$result = $gridFS->aggregate($ops);
```

With a foreach I get the result from this aggregate.
But how do I get the data from the file.
(with a normal query i do it like $obj2->getBytes();)

Comment: GridFS uses two collections for storage `fs.files` and `fs.chunks` by default. As such you cannot return the "content" in a single statement as it resides in another collection, and by definition in multiple documents. But any queries against `fs.files` allows acess to the unique identifier for each "file" contained with `fs.chunks`. Please understand these are just normal collections and there is nothing special from the MongoDB point of view. GridFS is software implemented in the "driver", that allows lookup and retrieval of these objects.

Comment: I understand that these are normal collections, so therefore it is possible to do normal queries.  But is it possible to get the binairy (Text) data from the fs.chunks?

Comment: Yes it's possible to get the data from `fs.chunks` and I already said it was. But you seem to be asking how to include that in your aggregate statement. You cannot as it is performed on a different collection.

Comment: That is correct. I tried it in the same aggregate statement.

Comment: Then which part about "No" and "because it is separate collections" is so hard to understand? MongoDB operations only ever occur on a single collection at a time. GridFS is not a "MongoDB feature", but a driver implemented spec, where functions look up data in one collection then use the results to do a separate query from another. This is the same thing you need to do here.